# Exclude smaller values than a threshold in R

Tags: r, extract

I have data in a tab-delimited text file like this:

```
FID  HV    HH     VOLUME
1    -2.1  -0.1   0
2    -4.3  -0.2   200
3    -1.4  1.2    20
4    -1.2  0.6    30
5    -3.7  0.8    10
```

These tables have mostly more than 6000 rows and much more columns.

I need to extract values of the column `VOLUME` smaller than e.g. 20.

I tried to do it with following command

```
x <- -which(names(x)["VOLUME"] > 20)
```

but it did not work.

Is there any method to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your data, try this:

```
x <- x[which(x$VOLUME <= 20),]
```

Comment: Probably "<=". The OP should be warned that the `-which()` construction is prone to bizarre results.

Comment: There's no need for `which` here anyway

Comment: it worked this way `treecv_sub1 <- treecv_sub1[-which(treecv_sub1$VOLUME < 20),]` Thanks!

Comment: The need for `which` is a matter of opinion. If you do not use which then you need to add `& !is.na(x$VOLUME)` if you wnat to avoid a long list of useless output when examine subsets where the test case might be comparing against vectors with NA's. @Soner: please look at `dat[ -which(dat$VOLUME >200), ]
[1] FID    HV     HH     VOLUME
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`. DON'T use `-which()`.

Answer (score 7):

Say your data is sample:

```
subset(sample, VOLUME<20)
```